# Connection information provided was for a non-administrative user fails in task scheduler

Tags: arcpy, scheduler

When attempting to use the arcpy.DisconnectUser function in a script that runs in task scheduler I receive the error 'Connection information provided was for a non-administrative user'.

I am able to run the script without any hiccups outside of task scheduler using the same connection. Prior to the script throwing the error it had been working properly. The connection uses windows authentication and the SDE DB connection is set up for sys and process admin.

Could this be a SQL permissions related problem?

Below is a sample of the code:

```
Admin = r'Database Connections\username.sde'
start = datetime.now()
resultsFile.write("Started process at - " + str(start)+"\n")
verList =[ver.name for ver in arcpy.da.ListVersions(Admin) if ver.name.lower() != 'sde.default'and ver.name.lower() != 'gisadmin.qaqc']
print "Created list of versions less default and QaQc at " + str(datetime.now())
resultsFile.write("Created list of versions less default and QaQc at " + str(datetime.now())+"\n")
arcpy.AcceptConnections(Admin, False)
arcpy.DisconnectUser(Admin, "ALL")
print "Disconnected users at " + str(datetime.now())
resultsFile.write("Disconnected users at " + str(datetime.now())+"\n")
```

Comment: You said you're using windows auth - which user account have you setup task scheduler to run with? Meaning, has anything changed with that user? (password, domain settings, etc)

Comment: My password did change within the past several weeks however, I updated it in Task Scheduler. Other than that nothing would have changed, domains remain the same.

Comment: Does it work if you use the full path to the connection file? I. e. c:\somefolder\anotherfolder\Database Connections\username.sde